# CGAL Minkowski Sum (exact offset) with General Polygons

Tags: cgal

With CGAL 5.0.2, is it possible to perform an exact offset on a General Polygon?

I've been examining the Minkowski examples and digging into the source code. I can generate a General polygon (based on conic arcs) from a simple unit square polygon (with straight edges). If I have a "rounded rectangle" that is defined as a general polygon with straight and curved segments - can I perform an exact offset on this rounded rectangle to obtain a larger rounded rectangle? I don't see anything in the source that allows this (or at least I couldn't understand how to do it while satisfying the templates).

Thanks to anyone who can help and advise me.

Answer (score 0):

No; this would be extremely hard; that is, computing the offset of a general polygons (in general). Imagine that the boundary of the general polygon can be algebraic traits for example. Computing the offset of a general polygon bounded by (line) segments and circular arcs is feasible, but it is not supported.